# Symfony2 - How to set the default choice for the entity field-type?

Tags: forms, symfony

How can I **pre-select** a value when using the **`entity`** field-type?

I would like to pre-select one of the countries fetched from database because most of our users live in the same country.

I was able to preselect a value within a `checkbox` field by adding the `data` option in the past.

This LocationType form is included by a UserType form as the form is build up from multiple entities.

**LocationType form:**

```
namespace Cmp\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Cmp\MyBundle\Entity\Account;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

    class LocationType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {

            $builder->add('company')
                ->add('street')
                ->add('streetno')
                ->add('streetsuffix')
                ->add('zipcode')
                ->add('city')
                ->add('province')
                ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'CmpMyBundle:Country',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                            ->orderBy('c.nameEn', 'ASC');
                    },
                    'choice_label' => 'nameEn',
                ))
                ->add('tel')
                ->add('fax')
                ->add('url')
                ->add('account', new AccountType());
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Cmp\MyBundle\Entity\Location',
            ));
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'location';
        }
    }
```

Herby the twig that generates to coutry list dorpdown.

```
       <div class="form-group {% if not form.location.country.vars.valid %}has-error{% endif %}">
            {{ form_label(form.location.country, 'country'|trans, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {{ form_errors(form.location.country) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.location.country, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'country'|trans}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller that generates the form:**

```
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserRegType(), $user);
```

The user type form includes the Location form type shown above.

Answer (score 0):

when you create your form you can assign a value to that field

for example:

```
$data = new Foo();
$data->setCountryCode($country);
$form = $this->createForm(new myFormType(), $data);
```

Comment: In my case this is not working because my form is a combination of two entities. These entity are linked with a ManyToOne link. So the new form start from the user and then includes its account. So the default value I want to set is in the other entity (account) as the one the new form starts with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace Cmp\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Cmp\MyBundle\Entity\Account;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $er;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $er) 
    {
        $this->er = $er;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('company')
            ->add('street')
            ->add('streetno')
            ->add('streetsuffix')
            ->add('zipcode')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('province')
            ->add('country', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'CmpMyBundle:Country',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.nameEn', 'ASC');
                },
                'data' => $this->er->FindOneBy(['country_code' => 'nl'])
                'choice_label' => 'nameEn',
            ))
            ->add('tel')
            ->add('fax')
            ->add('url')
            ->add('account', new AccountType());
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Cmp\MyBundle\Entity\Location',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'location';
    }
}
```

You need to inject the country repo in the service definition:

```
services:
    app.country_repository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - YOUR\COUNTRY\NAMESPACE\Country
    app.form.type.location:
        class: Cmp\MyBundle\Form\Type\LocationType
        arguments:
            - "@app.country_repository"
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Comment: That sounds logical, only how can I do that? I have tried the following code behind the 'data' field but get PHP error: $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Country')->findOneBy(array('countryCode' => "NL"))

Comment: Is your form defined as a service? Or do you build it in the controller? Can you post the complete class where you build the form, please?

Comment: It is defined as a formtype, I have added the complete code of this fromtype?

Comment: I've updated my reply. You need to inject the entity repository in service definition, you know how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the update, sorry don't know how to inject the entity?

Comment: can you update your question with the form service definition?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to Symfony, but is the LocationType form as I call it in my question not the form service definition? If so it is up to date.

Comment: No it's not, but anyway, can you post the code where you create the form? The class you posted is the form definition, how do actually create the form?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-cookbook-form-field-service

Comment: The twig file gets a `form` variable, this `form` variable is sent from a controller, the controller creates a form of type `LocationType`. Can you please post the code where the controller creates the form?